# iOS PFUser currentUser - Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, parse-platform

I am developing an iOS app using Parse and in my AppDelegate a check whether there is a user logged in or not the way the Parse docs tell you to:

```
if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
    // User Logged In - do stuff with the user
} else {
   // No User Logged In - Show Login/Sign Up View Controller
}
```

However, I get the warning "Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread." on the line [PFUser currentUser] all the time and the app crashes sometimes because of this. I've searched through Parse and all questions related to this have been removed for whatever reason and I am having a tough time figuring this out. I understand that warning but am unaware how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackground];
```